# Is there a way to set an input argument to a range of values?

Tags: ruby

I'm defining a method that takes a single argument:

```
def numbers(int)

end
```

I want a conditional statement that evaluates the argument against a range of values:

```
def numbers(int)
  if # int != (1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10) (not legal Ruby)
    puts "Cats"
  end
end
```

In this case, if `int` is not equal to `1`,`2`,`3`,`4`,`5`,`6`,`7`,`8`,`9`, or `10`, `puts "Cats"`.

Example:

```
def numbers(11) => "Cats"
```

How can I set up a range like this? I tried doing `!= (1..10)`, but that didn't work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [`Range`](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.3/Range.html)s:

```
def numbers(int)
  puts 'Cats' unless (1..10).include? int
end

numbers 11
# Cats
```

The `..` and `...` operators are used to create range literals. The former includes the last value, the latter excludes it.

```
1..10     # inclusive range; corresponds to the [1,10] interval
1...10    # exclusive range; corresponds to the [1,10) interval
```

Comment: And in Rails you can also write: `int.in?(1..10)`

Comment: Boring, but the way to do it.

Answer (score 5):

Just because:

```
def numbers(i)
  puts "Cats" unless (1..10) === i
end

numbers(3)
numbers(11)
  #=> Cats
numbers(0)
  #=> Cats
```

Comment: That is more direct than mine.

Comment: @sawa, where do you think I got the idea?

Answer (score 1):

Another (more readable) way to do it is by using [between](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.3/Comparable.html#method-i-between-3F):

```
def numbers(int)
  puts 'Cats' unless int.between?(1, 10)
end

numbers(3)
numbers(11)
  #=> Cats
numbers(0)
  #=> Cats
```

Answer (score 0):

```
def numbers(int)
  case int
  when 1..10
  else
    puts "Cats"
  end
end
```